# How can I make a live tile with Python on Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows-10

I've recently become interested in Windows 10's live tiles.

[image: A picture of the Windows 10 Calendar app live tile on the start menu]

In the picture above, the Calendar app's live tile is on, so it shows today's date. I would like to make one myself (in Python, because it's my most fluent language), that I can show my own custom images on it.

I've found [`mezzanine-live-tile`](https://pypi.org/project/mezzanine-live-tile/) in a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/cphizj/can_i_use_windows_10s_live_tiles_with_python/), but it does not seem to be maintained and it looks like it's for websites.

Are there any alternatives to [`mezzanine-live-tile`](https://pypi.org/project/mezzanine-live-tile/), or will I have to learn C# and code a Windows App?